# Upgrading Commerce 1 to Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

Folks:

I've got an e-commerce site that I'm upgrading. I've upgraded to Craft 3 and can reach the CP and the home page.

This site is tightly integrated with Commerce 1. When I visit the plug-in page, Commerce is listed but "missing". I've attempted to claim the license (using the license number listed on the plug-ins page) but the license number is not recognized.

Do I have any options other than purchasing a complete new license? Is there a way to use Commerce 1 with Craft 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run Commerce 1 on Craft 3.

Commerce was completely re-written for Craft 3 compatibility.  Indeed the final release of Commerce 2 actually requires Craft 3.1.

That said, your license for Commerce 1 should work for Commerce 2 once you have that installed but note there is a lot more to upgrading sites to Craft 3/Commerce 2 than just installing the new versions - there are extensive changes needed to both - including template and fundamental changes to custom plugins if you have written any of those.

See:

- https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html
- https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/changes-in-commerce-2.html